# Gateway Timeout Error Occurrs at Exact Same Spot in Program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, timeout

A website I help operate has a problem where when they need to upload a certain file, to run sql commands based off of data in it, it keeps giving them a gateway timeout error.

I tried running it locally and I get the same error in the same place, but the debug states that the sql commands are still running in the background when the timeout occurrs, and they appear to be successful.

I would believe it is a server error, but it concerns me that it happens only at this part. Could it be some kind of error in the code that causes this? If so, how can I fix it?

The program uses Java 6 and connects to an Oracle SQL Database.

Any kind of advice as to what could cause this kind of problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show some relevant debugging details.

Comment: And besides debugging details you've done, please [edit] your question to include what version of Oracle.  Are all input files causing problems?  Did this process ever work in the past?